# Can not use dynamic_cast to a const object

Tags: c++, constants, dynamic-cast, const-cast

I want to write a method where a `Base` object pointer will be passed as a parameter, and inside the method it will be casted to derived object pointer.

```
void func( const Base* const obj){
    Derived* der = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj);
}
```

But it shows error because **dynamic cast cannot cast away const specifier**. But I am  not understanding why `const` specifier has to be removed here, all I am doing is creating a *derived* pointer which should point to some offset amount after the *base* pointer. I also tried `const Derived* const der = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj);`, but no result.

It is important to pass the parameter as `const`. How can I do this? Do I have to do it in the ugly way of first applying `const_cast` then `dynamic_cast`? is there any better way?

Comment: just keep const `const Derived* der = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(obj);`

Comment: You need to keep `const` in the cast as well as the variable declaration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're casting away `const` because you didn't do this:

```
const Derived* der = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(obj);
```

If you actually need a `Derived*` then you need to

```
Derived* der = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(const_cast<ObjType*>(obj));
```

Comment: If you actually need a `Derived*` what you need is to redesign the solution.

Answer (score 8):

What you cannot do is *remove* the `const` qualifier with a `dynamic_cast`. If the types are polymorphic (have at least one virtual function) you should be able to do:

```
const Derived *der = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(obj);
```